# неправильные координаты мыши js canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

Почему координаты курсора неправильные?

[Весь код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kolichestvo/kvfsm49n/)

```
e.clientX - cvs.offsetLeft, e.clientY - cvs.offsetTop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере сanvas имеет какие-то некорректные пропорции. Т.е. не соответствие так сказать экранного пикселя пикселю canvas.

Если задать фиксированный размер для canvas, например 200 на 200 пикселей, а потом попробовать нарисовать

```
this.ctx.beginPath();
this.ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
this.ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
this.ctx.stroke();
```

То линия будет не по диагонали canvas.

Ну и в данном случае проблема решается использованием фиксированного размера для canvas и задания его не через CSS, а через аттрибуты width и height тега canvas

Рабочий вариант, с отладкой https://jsfiddle.net/kvfsm49n/1/

Comment: Огромное спасибо!